# Date Range issue using PHP, FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm having an issue with FPDF displaying a date range that I want displayed. It will pull every date from the beginning of the database every time. It doesn't matter what range I put it, it pulls from the start to the end date. Any assistance would be helpful.

Here is the Code:

```
      <?php
      define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');
       require('mysql_table.php');

        class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
       {
      function Header()
       {
       //Title
       $this->Image('eagle.png',10,6,30);
        $this->Image('eagle.png',170,6,30);
       $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
       $this->Cell(0,6,'Range Report',0,1,'C');
       $this->Ln(20);
        //Ensure table header is output
        parent::Header();
        }
        } 

        //Connect to database
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('charitabledb');

        $pdf=new PDF();
        $pdf->Open();
        $pdf->AddPage();
         //table: specify 4 columns
        $pdf->AddCol('date',20,'Date','C');
        $pdf->AddCol('transactiontype',30,'Transaction','L');
        $pdf->AddCol('account',40,'Account','L');
         $pdf->AddCol('description',60,'Description','L');
         $pdf->AddCol('Expense',20,'Expense','R');
         $pdf->AddCol('Income',20,'Income','R');
        $prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
        'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
        'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
        'padding'=>2);
        $startdate=$_Post['startdate'];
        $enddate=$_POST['enddate'];
         $pdf->Table("SELECT * FROM accounting WHERE date between '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . 
         $enddate . "' order by date ASC",$prop);

         $pdf->AddCol('',150,'');
         $pdf->AddCol('Sum(Expense)',40,'Total Expense','R');
         $prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
         'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
         'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
         'padding'=>2);
         $pdf->Table("select Sum(Expense) from accounting WHERE date between '" . $startdate . "' 
         AND '" . $enddate . "'",$prop);
         $pdf->AddCol('',150,'');
         $pdf->AddCol('Sum(Income)',40,'Total Income','R');
         $prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
         'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
         'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
         'padding'=>2);
          $pdf->Table("select Sum(Income) from accounting WHERE date between '" . $startdate . "' 
          AND '" . $enddate . "'",$prop);
          $pdf->AddCol('',150,'');
          $pdf->AddCol('Sum(Income)-Sum(Expense)',40,'Total Revenue','R');
           $prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
         'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
         'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
         'padding'=>2);
          $pdf->Table("select Sum(Income)-Sum(Expense) from accounting WHERE date between '" . 
           $startdate . "' AND '" . $enddate . "'",$prop);

           $pdf->Output();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your MySQL query... extracting from your code...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounting WHERE date between '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . $enddate . "' order by date ASC";
```

What are the formats of `$startdate` and `$enddate`? You might consider performing explicit casts on them to make sure MySQL does the right thing. I'm assuming date is a datetime column. If not, adjust accordingly.

WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' as datetime) AND CAST('$enddate' as datetime)

Short of that, you can print the output of that query and run that through the database separately. You can tweak the query until you get the expected results. If you could add a sample query here, that would help too.

As a side note, if this application is meant for a production environment, please escape any input coming from the user. Otherwise, you will run the risk of an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Could you give an example of escaping the input?

Comment: the column is called date. the variable is just date, not a datetime. I changed the statement to

Comment: "select Sum(Expense) from accounting WHERE date between    CAST('$startdate' as date) AND CAST('$enddate' as date)",$prop);